# vue3-runtime-template: [Vue warn]: Property "model" was accessed during render but is not defined on instance

Tags: runtime, vuejs3

I have been trying to use **vue3-runtime-template** in my vue3 sample project to compile custom vue templates on the fly. I also followed the configuration instruction provided by the official docs for this library:

```
// vue.config.js
module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: {
    resolve: {
      alias: {
        vue$: "vue/dist/vue.esm-bundler.js",
        // ...
      },
    },
  },
};
```

This should allow compiling at runtime.
When I use **Options API** (with data: () => ({attributes})), everything is fine and my model attribute will be unserstood by the runtime-template:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <v-runtime-template :template="template"></v-runtime-template>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import VRuntimeTemplate from "vue3-runtime-template";

export default {
  components: {
   VRuntimeTemplate,
  },
  data: () => ({
      model: "Audi RS7",
      template: `
        <h3>Hey, I am a car (model {{model}})</h3>
      `
  })
};
</script>
```

However, wenn I switch to the new Composition API, the template doesn't recognize the model attribute anymore and a warning is thrown:
[Warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ylQu.png)

This is the composition api aquivalent of options api based on my example, which causes the error:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <v-runtime-template :template="template"></v-runtime-template>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import VRuntimeTemplate from "vue3-runtime-template";
import { ref } from "vue";
export default {
  components: {
    VRuntimeTemplate,
  },
  setup() {
    const model = ref("Audi RS7");
    const template = ref(`
        <h3>Hey, I am a car (model {{model}})</h3>
      `);

    return {
      model,
      template,
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

Somehow there seems to be a difference between setup() and data(), and I frankly don't quite understand, why **model** stays invisible to vue3-runtime-template, if invoked with the setup().

I would really appreciate a good explanation.

Answer (score 1):

After I looked into the library source code, it became clear to me, why the plugin doesn't work with the composition api. The reason for that is that the properties you used to define in data(), computed, methods etc. were all accessible as attributes of this.parent under their respective names, now that all these things have been pressed into setup(), they are available as direct fields (i.e. if you have a computed value **someCompValue**, it is no longer under this.parent.computed['someCompValue'], but rather under this.parent['someCompValue']).

That is why there is no other way around than just to adjust this plugin manually to the composition api's structure.

**EDIT**: if you try to run throught this.parent object keys, you will probably receive a warning like "**Avoid app logic that relies on enumerating keys on a component instance. The keys will be empty in production mode to avoid performance overhead.**" In my production build it was actually the case and every attribute of this.parent was gone, which obviously led to malfunctioning of the plugin. I am still searching on it, but it seems like the plugin has some real struggle with accessing data of a parent component, when the parent is built with composition api.

**Further EDIT**
My solution to the problem from the previous edit was simply to pass the now missing properties of the parent element (like data, computed and methods) to the vue3-runtime-template as an extra prop and combine them with the properties that the plugin was able to extract on its own, like props, components etc.